# Logout due to inactivity after 5min with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to logout after 5 minutes of inactivity, I have this code, I'm just starting with mobile apps and I don't really understand how it works since my code doesn't logout (or does anything :( ), I don't understand if my code should implement it (send it to be called from some other activity) since this does not happen when selecting a button or something, it must be due to inactivity, so how is it executed? When I run my app it does not send me an error but it does not do it either (the rest in my app It works well)

```
class Logout : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var personsService: PersonsService

private var lastInteractionTime: Long = 0
private val INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 5 * 60 * 1000 
private val CHECK_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000

private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())


private val checkRunnable = object : Runnable {

    override fun run() {

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - lastInteractionTime >= INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT) {
          
           var request: CerrarSessionRequest = CerrarSessionRequest(false)
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
               val response = personsService.logoutVM(request)

                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
            applicationContext.startActivity(intent)

        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, CHECK_INTERVAL.toLong())
    }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
    applicationContext.startActivity(intent)


    // Start the inactivity check timer
    handler.postDelayed(checkRunnable, CHECK_INTERVAL.toLong())
}

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // Reset the timer every time the user interacts with the application
    lastInteractionTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    // Stop timer execution when stopping activity
    handler.removeCallbacks(checkRunnable)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand why or why not this will work, check out the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Specifically you can see if the onCreate method is going to be called then the activity as to be started which will bring it into the foreground. But if there is inactivity and or the user changes activities or apps, then this will go out of the foreground and that is the condition for onPause and the not being visible calls onStop, which in your code removes the call backs.

If you didn’t remove the callback then it would be a memory leak, and it could be killed automatically anyway.

There are other ways to achieve this behavior that would work:

- Use a single activity and move the logic there. Log the user out when the activity stops or 5 min goes by.
- Use the WorkManager or AlarmManager and every 2.5 min check if the app is in the foreground. On the third check in a row where they aren’t, log them out
- Have the timer logic moved to run on a Service in the background, not an activity